is there a way to use external data in Nextjs middleware?
I use NextAuth v5 in my middleware.ts as you can see in the code below:

 import { MiddlewareConfig } from 'next/server';
 import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
 import authConfig from '@/auth.config';
 import {DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,authApiRoute,authRoutes,publicRoutes} from '@/route.config'
 const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

export default auth((req) => {
 
   const { nextUrl } = req;
   const isLoggenIn = !!req.auth;

   const isAuthApiPath = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(authApiRoute);
   const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
   const isAuthRoute   = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

   if (isAuthApiPath){
    return; // just allow all NextAuth  API auth paths
   }

   if (isAuthRoute) {
     if (isLoggenIn) {
       return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
     }
     return;
   }

   if(!isLoggenIn && !isPublicRoute){
     return Response.redirect(new URL ('/auth/login',nextUrl));
   }

   return;
});

export const config:MiddlewareConfig = {
    matcher: [
        // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
        '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
        // Always run for API routes
        '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
      ]
}

the problem with this approach is, I have to fetch data to see which routes are accesible. because you might have right credentials as well but that part of the web app is not activated for you and so you can't access certain routes.
what I want, is to pass publicRoutes as a dynamic data, not just a static .ts file. but since middleware runs on Edge, it is not recommended and I don't know if it is even possible to fetch data there at first place.
according to Next js document:

Complex Data Fetching and Manipulation: Middleware is not designed for
direct data fetching or manipulation

what should I do?
